# Block automatic retaining, does it affect even to ivars in self?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, objective-c-blocks

If I have class:

```
@interface A : NSObject
{
    BOOL b;
    id   c;
}
@end
```

and reference `b` and `c` in a block, is the block retain `self` automatically? Or just `b` and `c`? About `c`, it may be retained itself, but how about `b`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bill's answer isn't quite correct:

If you have an instance of `A` and create a block inside of that instance like so:

```
^{
  b = YES;
}
```

Then `self` is retained (when the block is copied).  `b` is *not* `const`-copied, because `b` is strongly referenced by `self`, and only `self` is `const` within the scope of the block.

On the other hand, if you do:

```
BOOL aBool = YES;
^{
  aBool = NO;
  c = [[NSObject alloc] init];
}
```

Then again, `self` is `const`-copied (and retained when the block itself is copied) and the assignment to `c` is allowed.  However, the assignment to `aBOOL` is *not* allowed, because the value of `aBool` is `const`-copied.

In other words, the compiler recognizes the `b` and `c` are ivars, and will retain `self` instead of the ivars directly.

---

One way to think about this that helps me understand what's going on is to remember that an object is really just a fancy struct, which means you can technically access ivars via the arrow operator:  `->`

So when you're accessing ivars:

```
b = YES;
```

is *equivalent* to:

```
self->b = YES;
```

In that light, it makes perfect sense *why* you have to retain `self`, but `b` is not `const`.  It's because `b` is only a slim part of the "bigger picture", and in order to get `b`, you must necessarily include all of `self` as well (since copying part of a struct doesn't really make sense in this context).

Comment: by extension of this, when I pass 'self->b' to a method owned by another class/instance, or even a function - say 'foo(self->b)'. foo is declared as 'foo(id someObject)' and inside foo, is just one statement '[someObject retain]'. In this case, would 'b' alone be retained via 'someObject' or would 'self's retain count go up as well? In my understanding, once 'foo' receives the pointer to 'b' via 'someObject', it would not know about 'self' and hence would not retain 'self', only 'b'. This is a doubt I've had since starting work on ObjC - never had the chance/need to have it cleared!

Comment: @Dev only `b` would be retained

Answer (score 1):

Code from the block would be helpful in answering but assuming you have something like this;

```
^(A *a) {
    [a doSomething];
}
```

`a` will be retained by the block and released when the block is released. Nothing outside the ordinary will happen with `b` and `c`.

If you have something like;

```
^(id c, BOOL b) {
    [c doSomethingElse];
}
```

Then `c` will be retained by the block and `b` will be captured by the block as a `const` value (i.e. you would get a compiler error for doing `b = NO`)

For more details see the docs;

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1

Comment: Thanks! I got clarification about these details :)

Comment: Both of these examples show the block retaining something passed as a parameter to the block, rather than captured from the surrounding scope. The docs aren't clear on this point, but I would have expected that objects passed as parameters would not be implicitly retained, since they aren't defined until the block is actually called. Am I missing something?

Comment: @BJ Homer, you're right. Examples are wrong. But descriptions are right. I don't know what happened. I put +1 instead of picking as an answer.

Comment: @BJ Homer, I read documentation about block, and this answer does not look correct anymore. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1