# What data type do ivars for primitive properties have?

Tags: objective-c, properties, ivar

I am asking because the I was dabbling into some complicated block code and I did not expect the following code to work properly.

Say we have a BOOL property, as so:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isCancelled;
```

It's auto synthesised, no custom getter, no setter, no explicit ivar.

Then, there's this code... which works perfectly

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    id result = block(&_isCancelled);
    if (!_isCancelled) { ... }
}
```

However, I would have expected it work for the block() call, but not for the if, where I thought it would capture the value of _isCancelled and keep it const, not have it mutate throughout execution. Still, at runtime, the value of _isCancelled is always consistent inside/outside the block, as if it were actually BOOL *

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: No property is actually used in the given code, `_isCancelled` is just a normal *ivar* although declared implicitly.

Comment: Agreed, but because it is not declared explicitly, I could assume it to be declared as a pointer instead of a primitive. This could explain the behaviour (unless I'm missing something)

Comment: The type of the property is the same as the type of the backing ivar. Declaring property `BOOL isCancelled` means that an ivar `BOOL _isCancelled` will be synthesized. That's all.

Comment: Well then, why doesn't `_isCancelled` remain const inside the block?

Comment: @CatalinaM Why would it? It's an instance variable, not a local variable. The block is actually capturing `self`. Not the ivar. `_isCancelled` actually means `self->_isCancelled`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807022/block-automatic-retaining-does-it-affect-even-to-ivars-in-self

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Thank you! If you put this in an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When declaring a property `BOOL cancelled` the autosynthesized *ivar* is `BOOL _isCancelled`. This is a primitive variable, not a pointer.

However, when a block is capturing ivars, it is actually capturing `self`, not the ivar itself. Reading ivar `_isCancelled` actually means reading `self->_isCancelled`.

Therefore, ivars are not captured by value unless you save them into a local variable first (e.g. `BOOL isCancelled = _isCancelled`).

See [Block automatic retaining, does it affect even to ivars in self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807022/block-automatic-retaining-does-it-affect-even-to-ivars-in-self) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: The same type as the property.

All object pointers and primitive types are scalar values - i.e. singular values. They all need to be stored at an address in memory and therefore they all have memory addresses of their own.

By passing **&**`_isCancelled`, you're passing the *address* of the `BOOL` variable, so the `block()` has been "let in on a secret" - i.e. the location of the `BOOL` - so it can update it. Then afterwards you're checking the resultant *actual* value of `_isConnected`. This works for primitive types (scalars) and object pointers (also scalars).

Whether its a property or not is irrelevant.

Comment: That's what I though as well. I was expecting that `_isCancelled` is immutable inside the block (as it treats all vars inside the scope as _const_, so therefore it would always have the value it had when the block was evaluated). However, I suspect this behaviour has something to do with the fact that `_isConnected` is global and not scope local.

Comment: The value you're passing in _is_ const - it's the address of the BOOL. Nothing changes apart from the code block literally changing some bits at that address. Inside the block that variable is not a BOOL, it's a pointer to a BOOL.

Comment: My problem was with the if that followed the inner block execution. However, I now understand that `self` is actually retained, even if not directly referenced.